# Strange parent child relation JPA

Tags: jpa, parent-child

I have a table called menu - it has a date column and an item column e.g. '10/01/2023' : 'Veg Pizza'

Another table rsvp that has userid, menuid and size (small, med, large) e.g. userid 1 has rsvped for pizza on '10/01/2023' with size small.

Now there could be items in menu that the user has not rsvped for. I want to run a JPA (or native) query that takes a date range and userid as input e.g. 10/1 thru 10/7 and userid 1 and gives me 7 rows irrespective of whether there is user RSVP or not for it.

Keep in mind, my foreign key is in rsvp table on menu id and nothing in menu table.

```
CREATE TABLE `menu` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `rsvp` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `menu_id` int NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `less_carbs` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `adult_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `kids_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `menu_day_fk_idx` (`menu_id`),
  KEY `user_fk_idx` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `menu_day_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`) REFERENCES `menu` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I tried left outer join but I have a feeling this is not going to be a join thing and I may have to handle this in java. Please advice.

Thanks,
Asif

Comment: Can u explain what is rsvp stands for and what exactly a user is looking for. Pizzas he ordered in a specific date range??

Comment: RSVP means opting for something. So if I invite you and you say yes (or no) you rsvped to my invite.

Comment: Yes now i remember mail invite we use in daily life.

Comment: What your ask is when user provides a date and range and user id it should guve only rows which have been rsvped but currently it is giving all the rows??

Comment: No I want all records from menu table joined with rsvp but number of records should be driven by menu. So even if user has not rsvped for a particular day - the record should be returned with all null values from rsvp table.